# Remove duplicate template typename entry when inheriting

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++14, template-meta-programming

I have a template class I inherit from(From now on referenced as parent).

The template class initializes an fusion list member variable containing  classes and constructers specified in the child class.

```
template<typename... ITEM_TYPES>
using List = boost::fusion::list<ITEM_TYPES...>;

template<typename... CHILDREN_TYPES>
class ElementContainer 
{ 
protected:
    const List<CHILDREN_TYPES...> children;
public:
     ElementContainer(CHILDREN_TYPES&&... args) : children(forward<CHILDREN_TYPES>(args)...) {}
};
```

Example of a child class:

```
class XMLSignatureDocument : public ElementContainer<XMLDeclarationElement, SignatureXMLElement>
{
public:
    XMLSignatureDocument() :ElementContainer(
        XMLDeclarationElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"),
        SignatureXMLElement("<Signature xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\"></signature>"
        )) {};
};
```

When I create such a child class I have to specify the types of the classes in the list twice:

Once in the "inherit from" specification:

```
class XMLSignatureDocument : public ElementContainer<XMLDeclarationElement, SignatureXMLElement>
```

and also when I specify the constructor arguments of the individual classes:

```
XMLSignatureDocument() :ElementContainer(
    XMLDeclarationElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"),
    SignatureXMLElement("<Signature xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\"></signature>"
    )) {};
```

I would like to only have to specify it once- when I also specify the constructor arguments, something like this:

```
class XMLSignatureDocument : public ElementContainer<...>
{
public:
    XMLSignatureDocument() :ElementContainer(
        XMLDeclarationElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"),
        SignatureXMLElement("<Signature xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\"></signature>"
        )) {};
};
```

and still have compile time creation of the list in the parent class.

If it is not possible I am not locked 100% into this design- if it is possible with another design and accomplishes the same I would like to hear it.

I am using the Visual Studio 2014 (v140)(c++14) toolset for compilation- and the boost library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the opposite: specify types in the class declaration, and use universal initialization syntax for constructor arguments (though it won't work for explicit constructors):

```
class XMLSignatureDocument : public ElementContainer<XMLDeclarationElement, SignatureXMLElement>
{
public:
    XMLSignatureDocument() :ElementContainer(
        {"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"},
        {"<Signature xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\"></signature>"}
        ) {};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could construct your template argument types inside the `ElementContainer` constructor. This will work for `explicit` constructors, but only if they take a single argument.

Change the `ElementContainer` constructor to a template function which forwards the arguments on to the `CHILDREN_TYPES` constructors:

```
template <typename... Args>
ElementContainer(Args&&... args) 
    : children(CHILDREN_TYPES{std::forward<Args>(args)}...) {}
```

Then you can just pass the strings themselves:

```
XMLSignatureDocument() :ElementContainer(
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>",
        "<Signature xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\"></signature>") {};
```

Comment: Could a construct involving tuples and index sequences be made that allows packs of args to be passed to explicitly constructed parents?  I'm not seeing it, as we need a pack of packs of indexes and types, and these need to be unpacked over, but I could be wrong.  If we did not directly inherit (ie, had an intermediate helper) we could pull this off I think?

Comment: You mean something with usage `ElementContainer(std::make_tuple("..."), std::make_tuple("..."))` or something that works out those tuples implicitly?

Comment: How can I then declare the member variable children? The type is unknown if the types are not class template variables? Can you provide a full code example that compiles?

Comment: like this?template <typename... CHILDREN_TYPES>
class FuzzElementContainer 
{ 
protected:
 const fuzzList<CHILDREN_TYPES...> children;
public:
 template<typename... CHILDREN_TYPES>
 FuzzElementContainer(CHILDREN_TYPES&&... args) : children(CHILDREN_TYPES{ std::forward<Args>(args) }...) {}
                                               
 friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& streamReceiver, const FuzzElementContainer& streamSender)
 { 
  Printer printer(streamReceiver);
   for_each(streamSender.children, printer);
  
  return streamReceiver;
 }
};

Comment: @TartanLlama yes: some kind of emplace-magic, where the contents of each tuple are used to construct each element.  `ElementContainer( std::piecewise_construct{}, std::make_tuple(`.  I can do this with an intermediate helper that does the forwarding of the tuples (one at a time) to each base class, but I cannot figure out how to do it while inheriting directly.

Comment: @Yakk The best I could come up with was [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acd787d8bf6477d2), but I'm not sure exactly how many of those copies will be elided.